# How to turn off auto resizing for the Drawable folder?

Tags: android, image, resize

When I use a single Drawable folder, my images resize depending on the resolution of the device.

My current solution is to copy all the same images into each Drawable folder (hdpi, xhdpi, ldpi, mdpi), but that is making my APK file really big.

How can I disable the automatic resizing feature?

Comment: provide appropriate images for different densities and place them in appropriate drawable folders. You can also use webp for compression or use a .9.png

Comment: @Raghunandan Hmm yeah I just edited my question just now. I want to condense my APK file, because I am copying nearly a thousand images to each folder. Is there a way to only use one folder?

Comment: are using a .9.png? are you compressing your images?. http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: @Raghunandan I am not. Let me look into this. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Using resource folder `drawable-nodpi` may help.